# Laravel trying to get property of non object eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

Hi I am retrieving tasks in my tasks table in laravel. each task has a related status_id, these statuses are held in the statuses table, a user can also create their own statuses.

#### Status table

```
id | user_id | status_name
1  |  1      | low
2  |  1      | high
```

#### Task table.

```
id | user_id |status_id | task_name | task_brief
1  |  1      |2        | taskone  | brief
2  |  1      |1        | tasktwo  | brief
```

I want to retrieve all the users tasks, each task has a status e.g. Dev, Test, In Progress etc. This is reflected in the tasks table by the `status_id`. I'm trying to retrieve the status name so I can show this on a dashboard.  My query is correct as I have tested it using the following:

```
{{ '<pre>',print_r($user),'</pre>' }}
```

The data received is correct, from the task to the user to the status db details. However there seems to be a problem with the way I am retrieving the data in my `foreach` as I am getting the following error:

#### Trying to get property of non-object

I'm not sure whats going on but my code is below, would appreciate if somebody could help as my knowledge is quite limited.

UserController.php

```
public function opentasks() {

    $user = User::with(array('tasks', 'tasks.status'))->find(Auth::user()->id);
    return View::make('users.opentasks')->with('user', $user);

}
```

users/opentasks.blade.php

```
@foreach($user->tasks as $task)
    {{ $task->task_name }}
    {{ $task->task_brief}}
        @if($task->status->count() > 0)
            @foreach($task->status as $status)
                {{ $status->status_name }}
            @endforeach
        @endif
@endforeach
```

task.php

```
public function status(){
        return $this->hasOne('Status', 'id', 'status_id');
    }
```

user.php

```
public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany('Task', 'user_id');
    }
```

Routes.php

```
{
    Route::any("user/opentasks", [
    "as"   => "user/opentasks",
    "uses" => "UserController@opentasks"
]);
```

### EDIT

Table schema

Tasks table
[image]

Status Table

[image]

Error Logs

```
[2014-03-14 22:01:28] log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/app/storage/views/118f4221e407fdefc163f47a92f5bbe3:6
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/app/storage/views/118f4221e407fdefc163f47a92f5bbe3(6): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/Applications/X...', 6, Array)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(38): include('/Applications/X...')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(45): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/X...', Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(100): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/Applications/X...', Array)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(81): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(70): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php(141): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1414): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php(156): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepare(Object(Illuminate\View\View), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php(126): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->processResponse(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), 'opentasks', Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(985): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->callAction(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), 'opentasks', Array)
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(80): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(47): Illuminate\Routing\Route->callCallable()
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1016): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(574): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(550): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#18 {main} [] []
2014-03-14 22:01:28] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1429
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1050): Illuminate\Routing\Router->handleRoutingException(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException))
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1014): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(574): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(550): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/iTempus/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#5 {main} [] []
```

Comment: What does `dd($user)` on the view return?

Comment: @majimboo it outputs the correct data in an object

Comment: How about changing to `User::with('tasks', 'tasks.status')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();` ?

Comment: @majimboo `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`

Comment: fixed it, try again. edited the comment above.

Comment: @majimboo `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$tasks`

Comment: what line of code is giving you the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead

```
@foreach($user->tasks as $task) 
  {{ $task->task_name }} 
  {{ $task->task_brief}} 
  @if(!is_null($task->status)) 
    {{ $task->status->status_name }} 
  @endif 
@endforeach
```

You have some null values on the return, so check for it before trying to parse.
Also, you should be using belongsTo relationship on `task.status`.

Goodluck.

Comment: i get this error now: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$tasks` and tested Auth and the correct id was returned

Comment: try changing `->get()` to `->first()`

Comment: this throws me the original error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: can you share the Whoops stack trace?

Comment: i've updated question with printscreen of db tables and error logs

Comment: @g_9020 try doing a `composer dump-autoload` on your laravel root.

Comment: @g_9020 updated my answer. try modifying your view to that, and retry. seems like the error is on the view.

Comment: @g_9020 the problem seems to be on that line of code. Can you post a `dd($user->task)` before the foreach?

Comment: @g_9020 updated my answer. and it shouldve been `dd($user->tasks);`

Comment: @g_9020 pls post the `dd($user->tasks);` result. thanks. forgot the `s` on `tasks` from previews comment.

Comment: please download from my dropbox https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15618185/object.rtf quite a lot of text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49781/discussion-between-majimboo-and-g-9020)

Comment: can you come back to the chat for some reason even though the entry is null it shouldn't be the status_id is in the table but it is not returned?

Comment: if i include this file in my profile view `user/profile` by doing the following: `@include('users.openprojects')` i get this error: `Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception` why is that?

Comment: @g_9020 you might want to open another question for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417665/laravel-include-causes-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not