# Laravel include causes error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm including a file in laravel and its throwing me the following error:

```
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

I've included the file as so:

```
@include('users.opentasks')
```

I'm using two includes on the same page, but if I use one it doesn't make a difference.

I'm not really sure what this means and how to fix this bit of a newbie here. Hope someone can help.

My code is as follows:

UserController.php

```
public function profile() {
     $status = "closed";
    $data["projects"] = $projects = Auth::user()->projects()->where('status', '!=', $status) 
                                ->paginate(4);

    //$data["tasks"] = $tasks = Auth::user()->tasks->paginate(4);

      //  $data["tasks_pages"] = $tasks->links();

        //Comments pagination
        $data["projects_pages"] = $projects->links();


         if(Request::ajax())
            {

            $html = View::make('users.openprojects', $data)->render();
            return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
        //    $html = View::make('users.opentasks', $data)->render();
          //  return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
        }

        echo View::make('users.profile')->with('projects', $projects);

}

public function opentasks() { 

            $user = User::with(array('tasks', 'tasks.status'))->find(Auth::user()->id); 
            return View::make('users.opentasks')->with('user', $user); 

}
```

profile.blade.php

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
@include('users.openprojects')
@include('users.opentasks')
@stop
```

opentasks.blade.php

```
@foreach($user->tasks as $task) 
    {{ $task->task_name }} 
    {{ $task->task_brief}} 
            @if(!is_null($task->status)) 
              {{ $task->status->status_name }}<br/><br/><br/><br/> 
            @endif 
@endforeach
```

Comment: `echo View::make('users.profile')->with('projects', $projects);` change `echo` to `return`

Comment: that throws me a `undefined variable: user` error

Comment: That is because you @include the `opentasks` and `openprojects` which also need data. You have to pass those data with the view you returned too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do it like this:

```
if(Request::ajax())
{
  // --- this part of the code is odd
  $html = View::make('users.openprojects', $data)->render();
  return Response::json(array('html' => $html));
  // ---
} else {
  $user = User::with(array('tasks', 'tasks.status'))->find(Auth::user()->id); 

  $data = array(
     'user'     => $user,
     'projects' => $projects
  );

  return View::make('users.profile', $data);
}
```

Comment: that still gives me the undefined variable: user errror

Comment: amazing that worked. will accept in 4 minutes. also what is odd about that part of the code? I saw it in a tutorial online for an ajax call

Comment: @g_9020 I'm just not familiar with it... But I kinda get it now. (maybe). Its trying to return a json response of a rendered view :D